# Spring 3 Collection Binding

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

How I can bind a collection to a form for inputdata (not for show)

Answer (score 2):

e.g. for a `Set<Jokers>`

```
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(
        Set.class,
        "[nameOfTheClassMemberItShouldGoto]",
        new CustomCollectionEditor(Set.class) {
            protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
                return (element == null ? null : getQueryService().getJoker(element.toString()));
            }
        }
    );
}
```

or similar to this

Answer (score 0):

I did the same question and got a nice solution, take a look here  [How to bind a list of object to SpringMvc Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283920/how-to-bind-a-list-of-object-to-springmvc-controller)