# Bind same attribute names of multiple dynamically created fields using DTO

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have 2 dropdowns `A` and `B`.

- `A` is a normal dropdown
- `B` is a multiselect dropdown

`A` contains list of classes in a school and `B` contains divisions in a school

There is also a button for dynamic creation of these two dropdowns(There may be **n** dropdowns)

I want to save **n** dropdowns values simultaneously to my database but the problem is all my dynamically created field attribute names are same as the original two dropdowns, this way I am getting the value of last dropdown entered to my backend. I can dynamically change the attribute names using js, but I can't dynamically create variables in my dto.

I want my n dropdown values to bind into same DTO variables as a list or something like that, Is there any other methods to achieve this?
i researched and went up with `apache commons collections4` and `autopopulatingList` but i don't find any proper examples

**My DTO class**

```
public class TestDto {
    private Long fkcl;
    private String[] fkdiv;

    public Long getFkcl() {
        return fkcl;
    }
    public void setFkcl(Long fkcl) {
        this.fkcl = fkcl;
    }
    public String[] getFkdiv() {
        return fkdiv;
    }
    public void setFkdiv(String[] fkdiv) {
        this.fkdiv = fkdiv;
    }
```

**ClassDes**

```
public class ClassDes {

    public List<TestDto> list = new ArrayList<TestDto>();

    public List<TestDto> getList() {

        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<TestDto> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testing")
    public  ModelAndView ff(Model model) {


        ClassDes testprof = new ClassDes();
        List<ClassMaster> bslist = serv.findAllclass();
        model.addAttribute("blah", bslist);
        List<StudentMaster> std = stdServ.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("std", std);

         return new ModelAndView("test" , "testprof", testprof);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute ClassDes testprof) {

        System.out.println(BasicGson.toGson(testprof));

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/testing", "testprof", testprof);
    }
```

but my list returns empty `{"list":[]}` but in my ajax method,
 it shows

```
{"listed[].fkcl":"3","listed[].fkdiv":["1","2","3","4","5"]}
```

Comment: The question isn't clear, and has too much code. Do you want a JS solution to add elements to the dropdown or a data type to store in your server-side java?

Comment: @JoeyPinto No, i want to store all dropdown values  to my two dto variables as a list or something like that because i can't get the values in  my java side because it only takes first two dropdown values that matches the attribute name in my jsp

Comment: @JoeyPinto now i made some changes in the question,please check this

Comment: did you check the input from javascript?

Comment: Why dont you consider something as simple as a nested array list?

Comment: @JoeyPinto can you please be more specific about the nested array list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149119/discussion-between-joey-pinto-and-beginnerbro).

Comment: Will the number of attributes like list[].fkc1 change or is that constant?

Comment: it's not constant may be n,thats why iam telling you if the dynamically created attribute names are same then ajax will return only the last dropdown value or if i dynamically named the attribute's name along with 1,2,3...... then the dto doesnt catch it because it only contains 2 variables 
**{"listed[].fkcl":"3","listed[].fkdiv":["1","2","3","4","5"],listed[].fkcl1":"3","listed[].fkdiv1":["1","2","3","4","5"],listed[].fkcl2":"3","listed[].fkdiv2":["1","2","3","4","5"]}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can change ur submitform function in js

```
$('#submitForm').submit(function(e) {

            var frm = $('#submitForm');
            e.preventDefault();

            var data = {};
            var dt=[];
            var newdt = {};
            var Form = this;

            $.each(this, function(i, v) {
                var input = $(v);
                if(data.hasOwnProperty("fkcl")) //mapped all dropdown values to fkcl and fkdiv inorder to use `TestDto` variables
                    {
                    if(data.hasOwnProperty("fkdiv"))
                        {
                        dt.push(data);
                        data={};
                        }
                    }
                data[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
                delete data["undefined"];
            });


            newdt['list']=dt;
            alert(JSON.stringify(newdt));

            $.ajax({
                 async : false,
                global : false, 
                contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type : 'post',
                url : frm.attr('action'),
                data : JSON.stringify(newdt),

                success : function(callback) {
                    window.location.reload();
                },
                error : function() {
                    $(this).html("Error!");
                } 
            });
```

**@Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void save(@RequestBody ClassDes testprof) {

       for (TestDto t : testprof.getList()) {
        serv.save(t);
    }

        return new "redirect:/testing";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you've dynamically created an input section in your form, I think it's advisable to assemble all your inputs into a JSON object using javascript.

You can then send the JSON object as a single form parameter to the server where you can handle it the way you want. This will simplify the parameter handling process as you will have just one to work with.

Comment: Comment if you need a detailed explanation of how to do this.

Comment: i have the json data in my ajax but i want to pass that to my dto in rest controller

Comment: Like I said use it as a single parameter, Can you add the JSON to your question